# IDEA plugin like "WindowBuilder Editor" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

as we all know the "WindowBuilder Editor" in Eclipse is very useful, so when I change to use IntelliJ IDEA, I can't find the plugin. so my question is what's the plungin in IntelliJ IDEA, like "WindowBuilder Editor" in Eclipse? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't need to install any plugin in Intellij IDEA, there is already some GUI designer, have a look here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/components-of-the-gui-designer.html